# Why showing only 6 number after point though its a double?

Tags: c, double, precision

Here Is My Code -

```
#include <stdio.h>

double atof(char s[]); // This will convert string to double

int main(){
 char str[] = "3.14159265359";
 double d = atof(str);
 printf("%lf\n", d);
 return 0;  
}

double atof(char s[]){
 int i, frac = 0; // frac is for checking that s[i] is now after precision
 double n = 0.0, j = 1.0;
 for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
     if(s[i] != '.' && frac == 0){
         n = n*10 + (s[i] - '0');
     }
     else{
         if(s[i] != '.'){
             j *= 10.0;
             printf("%lf\n", ((double)(s[i] - '0') / j));
             n = n + ((double)(s[i] - '0') / j);
         }
         frac = 1;
     }
 }
 return n;
}
```

Input: 3.14159265359

Output: 3.141593

Why this is happening?

Comment: Even though we use `double` to aid intermediate precision, we rarely want to see that many decimal places in output.  A precision of 6 significant figures is generally enough (and often too much).  `printf` doesn't read your mind.  It just tries to be sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
printf("%.11f\n", d);
```

With the syntax `%.xf` you are able to specify the number of decimal digits (`x`) you want to print.

Answer (score 0):

Because the C language standard specifies for the %f conversion specifier that if "the precision is missing, it is taken as 6".